# Return date vs. returning date

Tags: meaning

Do "return date" and "[returning date](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/translation/returning+date.html)" mean the same thing? Thank you!

The Slot Return Date shall be the deadline for returning unwanted slots, [...]

[...] valid yet six months after returning date.

Comment: _Returning date_ isn't idiomatic English.

Comment: None of that text put together makes any sense. You would have to give more context.

Comment: I think that the main problem with this question is that you've taken your second example sentence from a website called "Linguee", which seems to use AI to translate texts and is therefore not a reputable source for valid English. Furthermore, it specifically says "External sources (not reviewed)", so no human at Linguee checked whether that sentence was valid. It does link to the source of the sentence (the website southamericandestination.com, which I've never heard of before), but the link gives a "404 page not found" error. I think that you've simply selected a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a definition:

"Return Date: The day when something needs to be given back or returned to its owner or original place. For example, if you borrow a book from the library, the return date is the day when you need to bring the book back to the library." - [www.lsd.law](https://www.lsd.law/define/return-date)

"Returning date" isn't idiomatic English. It might show up sometimes in text written or translated by non-native speakers.